# Latter allocation for derived class

Tags: c++

I know that memory for a derived class and it's base classes is allocated as one chunk. But is it possible to allocate additional memory for derived part, after base  class has been instantiated?
I suppose, that legally it can be done by reallocation, but what about additional memory?

```
class foo
{
int a, b;
//Some properties
};

class bar : foo
{
bool initialized;
};


int main()
{
foo *one = new foo();
bar *two = //magic;
}
```

`

Comment: It's not possible, since `bar` is a single unit that can't be split. The inheritance doesn't change that.

Comment: What you are asking for is sometimes called "object promotion", when an object of some class (foo in your example) is promoted to be an object of its subclass (bar) at run time. It is a rare feature of object-oriented languages. C++ doesn't support it. You can however create a completely new bar object which will contain a copy of the original foo object.

Comment: @n.m. interesting. What languages do support this feature?

Comment: @bolov I don't remember the name, it was some kind of experimental language where all objects were constructed through promotion. And they referenced similar work. I cannot find any of this now.

Comment: @bolov of course then there's `become:` of Smalltalk, but it's in a league of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's impossible. As you said it yourself, the base and the derived parts of an object are allocated in one chunk of memory. But not only that, even if a bigger memory chunk is allocated upfront, and only the base part (`foo`) is constructed, it is impossible to construct only the derived part (`bar`) later.

**Note that this is very low level, and should never be done in regular code, unless you are implementing something like `std::variant<T,U,...>`, which most likely you aren't.**

Here is how you construct specific object types at a given memory block:

```
int main()
{
   // this is the allocation
   char *block = new char[sizeof(bar)];

   // and this is only the construction
   foo * one = new (block) foo();
   // The memory block is big enough for bar, 
   // but there is no way to construct only the bar part
   bar * two = // magic is not possible
        // this will construct both bar and its parent foo.
        // This is bad, since the foo part is constructed twice.
        new (block) bar();

   delete[] block;
}
```

The best thing is to destroy and to reconstruct the object (**don't do it, unless you are implementing a low level library)**:

```
int main()
{
   // allocate the memory
   char *block = new char[sizeof(bar)];

   foo * one = new (block) foo();
   work with one....
   one->~foo(); // destroy it.

   // construct it again, using the derived type.
   bar * two = new (block) bar();
   work with two
   two->~bar();  // don't forget to destroy.

   // deallocate the memory.       
   delete[] block;
}
```

All this effort, and nothing is gained over a couple of separate and independent `new` and `delete`
 pairs.

Comment: Ok. Consider this: 
I am allocating memory for derived class, call constructor in place for parent. Then reinterpret cast to derived and assign all derived class&amp;#39;s members.
It surely works, so as deleting. But there comes the question: what is the difference between using constructor to initialize fields and doing it manually?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik this invokes undefined behavior. The real object-type is the base class, and you are referring to it (after `reinterpret_cast`) as the derived class, which is a different type, and the object was not constructed as such (which is not permitted). These tricks may confuse the compiler, which can lead to unexpected results (like any other undefined behavior). Then, the derived class was never constructed - its fields are uninitialized. If your idea works, then it is only by pure luck, and it may fail unpredictably.

Comment: But what about using static and dynamic casting? It is stated that I can use static, if I surely know, that base class is allocated on the memory of derived. Or do I get it wrong?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik dynamic casting makes sense when there is a virtual table, i.e., there are virtual functions. With dynamic casting the situation is worsened since the pointer to the virtual table has to be modified when the subclass is constructed. The type system is more than just blocks of memory. It is more difficult to create a bad example in your case, because the compiler is more careful about reordering read/write for base/derived classes, but they are still distinct types. reinterpret_cast to a different and bigger object than was constructed is calling for trouble

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik regarding `static_cast`: its only defined to "downcast" (from foo to bar) and access through the resulting pointer if the pointer you are passing into static_cast is really pointing to a constructed bar object. Otherwise its undefined behaviour. static_cast wont do any runtime checks